# using XPath need help in getting the value of an Element from a XML file and then creating a list with those values

Tags: xml, xpath

I have had no problem in doing the same thing with Attributes from an XML file. I was able to do so in the following way:

I declare my XML document

```
static XDocument cfgXml;
```

I click a button and browse to my XML file and select it.

```
private void selcFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
          DialogResult result1 = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            string xmlFile = openFileDialog1.FileName; 

          if (result1 == DialogResult.OK)
            {
              cfgXml = XDocument.Load(@xmlFile);
           }
        }
```

I have a class to create a List

```
class DiskPoolDisks
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public DiskPoolDisks(string a)
            {
                this.id = a;
            }
        }
```

I click a button to load and create my list

```
private void loadCfg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
List<DiskPoolDisks> pooldiskArray = new List<DiskPoolDisks>(from d in cfgXml.XPathSelectElements("//Configuration//ServerGroup//Servers//Server//DiskPools// PhysicalDisks//PhysicalDisks") select new DiskPoolDisks((string)d.Attribute("id")));
}
```

Now I need to do the same form a different XML file that contains Elements for which I need to create a List from their Values.

However trying to use the same method above does not work, I get a list with a count of zero, where I should have at least one Value in the List.

```
static XDocument objXml;


private void selcObjFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
           DialogResult result2 = openFileDialog2.ShowDialog();
            string xmlFile = openFileDialog2.FileName;


            if (result2 == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                objXml = XDocument.Load(@xmlFile);
            }
        }

private void loadCfg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
List<CdpHistory> cdphistoryArray = new List<CdpHistory>(from d in objXml.XPathSelectElements("//DataRepository//StreamLogicalDiskData//MinQuota")
select new CdpHistory((string)d.Attribute("Value")));
}
```

My XML file that I'm trying to get the Value from the MinQuota Element in the following XML file

```
<Repository>
<StreamData>
 <SequenceNumber>63066</SequenceNumber>
 <Id>188804e8-c579-438c-8a17-1d1f2ce89d17</Id>
 <Caption>Caption goes here</Caption>
 <ExtendedCaption>Log history </ExtendedCaption>
 <Internal>false</Internal>
 <Server>949303A9-8472-4979-9EA0-A807831574AE</Server>
 <DataStatus>Undefined</DataStatus>
 <PresenceStatus>Present</PresenceStatus>
<Size>
 <Value>1125899906842624</Value>
 </Size>
 <MappingName>mapping one</MappingName>
 <Status>Online</Status>
 <Virtualized>false</Virtualized>
 <AccessRights>NotDefined</AccessRights>
 <Failure>Undefined</Failure>
 <Role>Unknown</Role>
 <IsMapped>false</IsMapped>
 <Protected>true</Protected>
 <Id>949303A9</Id>
 <Index>10</Index>
<MinQuota>
 <Value>11811160064</Value>
 </MinQuota>
<MaxQuota>
 <Value>0</Value>
 </MaxQuota>
<Affinity>
 <int>1</int>
 <int>2</int>
 <int>3</int>
 </Affinity>
 <State>Idle</State>
 <Time>0</Time>
<Size>
 <Value>0</Value>
 </Size>
 <State>NotPresent</State>
 </StreamData>
 </Repository>
```

Comment: For starters, the XML file structure doesn't match the XPath expression you provided. Second, the MinQuota value is not stored in the document as an attribute but as a child node with text content. Are you sure the code and data are correct as posted?

Comment: Here is my challenge, I'm new to C#, no previous coding experience and learning as I go and find examples on the net as personal challenge at work.  The XML file structure was created by another developer and we cannot change the structure of the XML file so I have to use the structure that I have.  Thank-you for pointing out that the MinQuota is a child node with text content.  How how can I revise my code to be  to retrieve the text content from a child node?  The same code to create the needed lists worked for the Attributes of a different XML file so I thought the logic should work too.

Comment: I don't know what your CpdHistory class looks like, but the following  expression will select the child values node of any MinQuota nodes "//Repository/StreamData/MinQuota/Value". You want the text node value, not an attribute, so something like the following should work: 
new List<CdpHistory>(from n in xml.XPathSelectElements("//Repository/StreamData/MinQuota/Value")
select new CdpHistory(n.Value));

Comment: class CdpHistory
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public CdpHistory(string a)
            {
                this.id = a;
            }

        }

Comment: I tried the code that you have place here, but still I get nothing back for this particular XML file that has child nodes with text content.  The List is created but with nothing in it and a count of 0.  If I were to modify it slightly to point to the other XML file and give it a path to an Element and use d.attribute("x") then the same new List<CdpHistory> will create a CdpHistory list but populated with the values of the Elements from the other file.  Thus I cant have a mistake in the class and the new List<CdpHistory> call works.  I just cant figure out how to get the Tex Value.

Comment: OK it seems like that under <Repository> there are there is a namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there was a namespace in the XML file, so I had to add the following:

```
private void selcObjFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
           DialogResult result2 = openFileDialog2.ShowDialog();
            string xmlFile = openFileDialog2.FileName;


            if (result2 == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                objXml = XDocument.Load(@xmlFile);
                nsm.AddNamespace("dat", "http://www.abc.com/");
                nodeList = root.SelectNodes("//dat:StreamData/dat:MinQuota", nsm);
            }
        }
```

having done that then the following allowed me to create the list that I needed:

```
List<string> cdphistoryArray = new List<string>();

            foreach (XmlNode MinQuota in nodeList)
            {
                if (MinQuota.LastChild.InnerText != "0" && MinQuota.LastChild.InnerText != null)
                {
                    cdphistoryArray.Add(Convert.ToString(MinQuota.LastChild.InnerText));
                }

            }
```